# Reshaping a table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL and currently have a large table that contains data for 1000's of accounts sorted by date:

```
ID   July 2018    August 2018    September 2018    …
1       10            20             30
2       50            40             10
3       20            10             80
```

I need to reshape the table so the table is displayed like this:

```
   ID     Month          Value   
    1   July 2018         10 
    1   August 2018       20    
    1   September 2018    30
    :        :             :
```

I don't know how to do this or if this is even possible. I have tried to use the `pivot` function in SQL but I have not been successful. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: My Table or my database? Table is called Account_details. Database is called AccountsEC19. All of this data is in a table

Comment: your dbms name?

Comment: Account_details

Comment: I mean your database server name?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I have added the DBMS: Sql-Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use unpivot - it will work in MSSQL

```
select t.id, up.months, up.value
from tablename t
unpivot
(
  value
  for months in ([July 2018], [August 2018], [September 2018])
) up;
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. For some reason I was using pivot rather than unpivot which makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT t.id, tt.*
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES ('July 2018', [July 2018]), 
              ('August 2018', [August 2018]), 
              ('September 2018', [September 2018])
     ) tt (Month, Val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the help of `UNION` operator:

```
select id, 'July 2018' as Month, July2018 as value from <table>
UNION
select id, 'August 2018' as Month, August2018 as value from <table>
UNION
select id, 'September 2018' as Month, September2018 as value from <table>
```